# MySQL Dual-Primary Replication

Tags: mysql, centos5, replication

I have 2 identical up to date dedicated MySQL servers and I just configured dual-primary replication on both, everything works as expected but the problem is that I have a lot of BIN files with very old events which doesn't exist anymore and once the replication starts, I get a lot of errors which if I choose to skip manually I will be doing it forever and somehow the mysql table gets screwed and I can't access mysql anymore so is there a way to tell the replication, you're fine and fully synced now and everything happens later sync it and delete those bin files on both servers?

Comment: If you're getting errors when you start replication, than either a) You don't actually have two identical up-to-date servers or b) you're starting replication using the wrong binary log/position.  I'd suggest starting at the beginning and figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: you're absolutely right, I was applying old logs on new databases which doesn't make sense, I purged all the logs, dumped all databases from one server to the other and started slaves and now I am up and running, thank you so much for the hint :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your both servers synced, with replicated paused, use :

```
PURGE MASTER LOGS BEFORE now()
```

on both server. This will reset the binary log on both servers (and remove the old files).

Make sure to check the file name and position with :

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS
```

Then, you'll need to reset the position with (on both servers) :

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE=mysql-bin.000001,MASTER_LOG_POS=106
```

Example of a show master status:

```
mysql> show master status;
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position  | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000228 | 359641126 |              |                  |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yes, yes and yes, you're right and this is worked like a charm, thank you :))